# Confused about OSGi version 4.3 and Felix

Tags: osgi, equinox, apache-felix

I don't quite understand the OSGi version of the latest Apache Felix version (4.0.2).

I've read that Apache Felix 4 is OSGi 4.3 compliant, and I *thought* that that implied that the Felix framework package would export org.osgi.framework version 1.6.0.

It does not, a quick peek into the manifest of Felix says it exports version 1.5.0, so (at least) one of these assumptions is wrong. If I check Equinox 3.7 I *do* see an export of org.osgi.framework version 1.6.0

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have read the export wrong. Felix 4 is an OSGi R4.3-compliant framework, and it does export `org.osgi.framework` version 1.6.0.

**UPDATED 23 Oct 2014**

The above refers to Felix version 4.2, which was the highest version available at the time. The current release of Felix (4.4) now supports OSGi Release 5 APIs.

Comment: You are so right, I misread one of the 'uses:="org.osgi.frame
 work";version="1.5"' clauses as an actual export. Sorry for wasting your time ;-)

Comment: No problem. I know that the uses constraints can make it difficult to read.

Comment: @NeilBartlett - you can say that again! The 80-column wrap is an abomination, too.

Comment: @ChrisDolan Yes. You might want to try installing [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) as a command line tool. Then you can get a nicely formatted version of the manifest (along with lots of other useful info) by typing `bnd print filename.jar`

Comment: just 'bnd *.jar' will do, print is the default command for jars.

Comment: Things have changed, now Felix supports OSGI R5 since version 4.4.0